# Converting Danish special characters

Tags: matlab, unicode, file-io, special-characters, matlab-table

I'm trying to read a `.csv` file for my script, but the script contains the special danish characters "æ","ø" and "å". So far my idea was to define it like this:

```
CellM = readtable(csvdata,'Format','%æ%ø%å%s');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"? Please add error informations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to explain what you are trying to achieve, why you're doing what you're doing, and what you're currently getting. You should be very specific when describing your problem, unless you want to get your question closed. At the moment, it's unclear what your difficulty is. See also: [mcve].

Comment: can you add some lines of your csv-file to the question to illustrate your problem better?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the file **encoding** when you call [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#btx_238-1-Encoding):

```
readtable(..., 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

This should solve your problem, assuming you didn't use another function on `csvdata`, earlier, which already messed your data up.

Comment: Thank you Dev-iL! The added code to my read function allowed the script to load the data. However instead of leaving the special danish characters as they were, they are replaced with a special character like an inverted ? and 3/4. Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a different encoding like `windows-1252`, `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-4` etc. `UTF-8` was just a guess, and judging by your comment, it wasn't a good one...